# Can a machine learning model provide information about mean and standard deviation of data on which it was trained?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, data-science

Consider a parametric binary classifier (such as Logistic Regression, SVM etc.) trained on a dataset (say containing two features for e.g. Blood Pressure and Cholesterol level). **The dataset is thrown away and the trained model can only be used as a black box (no tweaks and inside information can be gathered from the trained model)**. Only a set of data points can be provided and their labels predicted.

Is it possible to get information about the mean and/or standard deviation and/or range of the features of the dataset on which this model was trained? If yes, how so? and If no, then why can't we?

Thank you for your response! :)

Comment: This question is not about programming and should instead be asked at http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

SVM does not provide any information about the data statistics, it is a maximum margin classifier and it finds the best separating hyperplane between two datasets in the feature space, as a linear combination of "support vectors". If you use kernel functions, then this combination is in the kernel space, it is not even in the original feature space. SVM does not have a straightforward probabilistic interpretation whatsoever.

Logistic regression is a discriminative classifer and models the conditional probability p (y|x,w) where y is your label, x is your data and w are the features. After maximum likelihood training you are left with w and it is again a discriminator (hyperplane) in the feature space, so you don't  have the features again.

The following can be considered. Use a Gaussian classifier. Assume that your class is produced by the prior class probability p (y). Then a class conditional density p (x|y,w) produces your data. Then by the Bayes rule, you will have: p (y|x,w) = (p (y)p (x|y,w))/p (x). If you define the class conditional density p (x|y,w) as Gaussian, its parameter set w will consists of the mean vector m and covariance matrix C of x, assuming it is being produced by the class y. But remember that, this will work only based on the assumption that the current data vector belongs to a specific class. Conditioned on w, a better option would be for mean vector:   E [x|w]. This the expectation of x with respect to p (x|w). It comes down to a weighted average of mean vectors for the class y=0 and y=1, with respect to their prior class probabilities. Same should work for covariance as well, but it needs to be derived properly, I am not %100 sure right now.

Comment: Thanks, I will try taking Bayes rule and Gaussian distribution into consideration to get an idea of how to approach this problem. :)